# Call function inside component from different component

Tags: reactjs

I'm using react and I have 2 components. Inside Comp1 I have a function that I want to call inside Comp2. How could I do this?

Code:

```
    const Comp1 = () => {
    
    // Call handleSetSearch in Comp2 
    const handleSetSearch = () => {
        const value = document.querySelector('.ais-SearchBox-input').value;
        console.log(value)
    };

    return (
    <>
       ../
    </>
    );
}

const Comp2 = (handleSetSearch) => {
    return (
        <div>
         <p onClick={ComparisonSearch}></p>
        </div>
    )
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `react`, using `props` to communicate with components is very common. For example, if the relation between `Comp 1` and `Comp 2` is parent to child, you can acquire the function of `handleSetSearch` by using `props`.

```
Const Comp1 = () => {
  const handleSetSearch = () => {
    const value = document.querySelector('.ais-SearchBox-input').value;
    console.log(value)
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Comp2 handleSetSearch={handleSetSearch} />
    </>
  )
}

Const Comp2 = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p onClick={props.handleSetSearch}></p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

If you want to add parameter in the function of `handleSetSearch`. Here is a example.

```
const handleSetSearch = (params) => {
  console.log(params)
};

<p onClick={() => props.handleSetSearch('123')}></p>
```

Comment: Would I be able to pass a value through props.handleSetSearch to handleSetSearch function?

Answer (score 0):

You should use **Comp2** as a child in **Comp1** and pass **Comp1** function into **Comp2** as props.

```
const Comp1 = () => {
    const handleSetSearch = () => {};
    return (
    <>
      <Comp2 handleSetSearch={handleSetSearch} />
    </>
    );
}


const Comp2 = ({handleSetSearch}) => {
    return (
        <div>
         <p onClick={() => handleSetSearch()}></p>
        </div>
    )
};
```